# Linear regression not converging

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, colab

I'm trying to implement the simplest possible machine learning algorithm which is linear regression. But I'm having trouble because the loss function is not converging. Please can you look at my notebook and see where my mistake is? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/171nVbjXvH6VcbpwwGHEASXn90RwOnDZB?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

My learning rate was too high!